# JS разбор ответа от api.vk.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vkontakte-api

Добрый вечер. Помогите пожалуйста. Нужно на js разобрать ответ от API ВКонтакте. Вот моя функция:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "https://api.vk.com/method/audio.get?user_id=XXX&shuffle=1&count=1&access_token=XXX",
dataType: "jsonp",
success: function(response){
alert(response.response['url']);
}
});
};
```

Получаю такой ответ:

```
{"response":[{"aid":456239060,"owner_id":XXX,"artist":"The White Buffalo &amp; The Forest Rangers ","title":"Come Join the Murder","duration":450,"url":"https:\/\/cs7-3v4.vk-cdn.net\/p21\/2d8df3cdd8131f.mp3?extra=p7gw8f1MeLhsDampJ_ZEaAB-JOOo6BtKbsR6lX-EQAfEj482z9dotFcRD_YgRnwIKBG62F9clyqAmmGk6bRXmuR9ay3KOgnXt3BK-375NgHBi0iU7hQxkbiD3aRlzU2KB6_qnKJ-uLAZL74","genre":1001}]}
```

И никак не могу вытащить artist, title и url. Знаю реализацию на php, но нужно именно на яваскрипте. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: `response.response[0]['artist']`, `response.response[0]['title']`, `response.response[0]['url']` ......... массив же

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо! точно, работает